# Problema com background no Header do DataGrid

Tags: wpf, datagrid

Tenho o seguinte bloco de código definindo o estilo do Header no meu xaml:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="DimGray"/>
                    <Setter Property="Height" Value="45"/>
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
                    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Calibri"/>
                    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="20"/>
                    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="15 0 0 0"/>
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                </Style>
```

Quando o valor da propriedade `HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"` o resultado é esse: [image: Data Grid]

Mas quando mudo o valor para `HorizontalAlignment="Center"` acontece isso: [image: Data Grid2]

quero que fique centralizado mas com o background todo preenchido.

Comment: Deixe o `Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"`  e inclua mais uma tag `HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"`.

Comment: Não deu certo :(

Comment: Uma propriedade sobreescreveu a outra